# Can I tell Siri not to yell in my ear?

Tags: iphone, siri

I keep forgetting how loud Siri can be.

I ask Siri to call someone and lift my phone to my ear and Siri yells in my ear hard enough to hurt that it is making the call.

Yes, that is stupid of me.   But is there a setting to tell Siri not to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Settings >> Accessibility >> Siri >> Prefer Silent Responses

Comment: I want a response, I just want SIRI to recognize when the phone is at my ear and switch to the volume that it uses for phone calls.

Answer (score 0):

a la Google: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209573

## How to change Siri volume

Change how loudly or softly Siri speaks on your iPhone, Apple Watch, Mac, or HomePod.

## Change Siri's volume on your iPhone

You can ask Siri to change your volume settings. Just say "Hey Siri, speak louder" or "Hey Siri, speak quieter."
If you want to change the volume when Siri is speaking or when you're using headphones, press the Volume buttons on the side of your iPhone.

Comment: Volume is good until I move my phone to my ear to use it as a phone, then it doesn't adjust to phone volume.